# strange behaviour with bootstrap close

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have two buttons in my markup like so

```
<button class="close" type="button">x</button>

<button class="pull-right btn btn-primary" style="margin-right:5px;" id="btnAddEndorsement" data-endorsee-id="{{personId}}" data-endorser-id="{{ EndorserId }}">Endorse</button>
```

These buttons are bound to my own close function, but bootstrap is removing the parent element itself first, which is causing display issues.

I understand this is correct with the "close" class applied to a button, but cant figure out why "btnAddEndorsement" is also trying to hide its parent div, any ideas?

Failing that is there a way to use bootstrap classes without firing the events?

Comment: you mean for modal close?

Comment: yeah. bootstrap close

Comment: Can you include all your code including your close function?